# How can I throw an exception from within an MLflow project?

Tags: python, exception, mlflow

I have an Mlflow project that raises an exception. I execute that function using `mlflow.run`, but I get `mlflow.exceptions.ExecutionException("Run (ID '<run_id>') failed")`.

Is there any way I could get the exception that is being raised where I am executing `mlflow.run`?

Or is it possible to send an `mlflow.exceptions.ExecutionException` with custom message set from within the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not at the moment. mlflow run starts a new process and there is no protocol for exception passing right now. In general the other project does not even have to be in the same language.

One workaround I can think of is to pass the exception via mlflow by setting run tag. E.g.:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as ex:
    mlflow.set_tag("exception", str(ex))
```