# How to handle errors in MLflow when a model has been served using "mlflow models serve"?

Tags: python, rest, mlflow

During training, it is possible to use tags as a way to handle exceptions according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59856641/how-can-i-throw-an-exception-from-within-an-mlflow-project).

If a model has been created using `mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel`, is it possible to throw exceptions? Is there a way to allow error handling for a model that has been served?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to to catch exception in your overridden `predict()` [method](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.pyfunc.html#mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel.predict) for the `mlflow.pyfunc.PyModel` and log it.

Comment: Since we expose the model as a REST API when we serve it, what should be returned in case of exception?